# Carousel-style slide transition in VueJS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a component that is basically a carousel: a sequence of full-page divs that slide in and out of view when the user swipes left and right.

I'm...kind of there. When I swipe, the old view slides out as desired. The new view does not slide in at the same time, though: it just appears after the previous transition is complete. Vue enter/leave transitions happen simultaneously, so I'm probably doing something wrong.

(I realize a slide left happens regardless of swipe direction. That's a detail I can address later, [hopefully using this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761660/vuejs-2-previous-and-next-transition).)

**Carousel component**:

```
<template>
    <div class="slide" v-hammer:swipe.horizontal="onSwipe">
        <transition name="slide">
            <SliderPane v-for="pane in panes"
                :key="pane.position"
                v-if="pane.position === currentPane"
            />
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import SliderPane from './SliderPane';

export default {
    name: 'Slider',
    components: {
        SliderPane
    },
    props: {
        panes: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            currentPane: 1
        };
    },
    methods: {
        onSwipe(event) {
            const lastPane = this.panes.length;

            if (event.deltaX < 0 && this.currentPane < lastPane) { // Swipe right.
                this.currentPane++;
            }
            else if (event.deltaX > 0 && this.currentPane > 0) { // Swipe left.
                this.currentPane--;
            }

            // Do nothing if on first/last panes.
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">

.slide-leave-active,
.slide-enter-active {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.slide-enter {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}

.slide-leave-active {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
    .slide
    {
        display: flex;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

**SliderPane.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div class="sliderPaneContainer">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'SliderPane',
    props: {
        index: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    div.sliderPaneContainer
    {
        height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: stretch;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Care to share your insights?

Comment: @PrintlnParams Nope. This was a job application project, and I ended up submitting it broken. Needless to say, I did not get the job...